# How to wire 0.91/0.86 inch display to i2c?

Tags: arduino, i2c, wiring, display, oled

[image: 0.86 inch display]

I have a 0.91 inch display with a 4 pin I2C connection. I then realised that I needed to use a 0.86 inch display with the connector in the above image. I have searched on google on this but nothing has come up. Are there any suggestions on how to connect this? Below is a part of the datasheet if that helps.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to connect it to?

Comment: Where is the part of the datasheet with the contact table?

Comment: This looks like very common 14-pin display with SSD1316 driver. The [driver datasheet](https://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/controller/SSD1316.pdf) is all over the web, although pinout can be manufacturer-specific. Generally you need 2 to 6 external capacitors and pull-ups for I2C. If you are asking about physical connection, then from the picture it is 0.62mm pitch FPC. I am not aware of ready-made connectors with this pitch, so you might have to make suitable pads on PCB and solder this cable directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a connector, the 0.62mm pitch connector is an oddball, apparently only available from a couple of Chinese manufacturers, eg. Wenda LW06121. Suggest you ask the display supplier to source them for you. They list similar connectors for a very reasonable price. However the datasheet refers to "Soldering Type FPC" so it looks like it's mainly intended to be soldered to the PCB directly (and being single-sided that's not a problem).

Electrically, you can refer to the [full datasheet](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/manual/ER-OLED0.86-1_Datasheet.pdf), which is pretty complete but does not have a reference schematic, plus the [driver chip datasheet](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/SSD1316.pdf?tdsourcetag=s_pcqq_aiomsg), plus this demo circuit schematic:

[image]

As you can see, there's a couple of charge-pump capacitors C1/C2, some bypass capacitors, a resistor to set the OLED current, and the usual pullup resistors on the SDA/SCL I2C data and clock lines.

There's also demo code available.

Comment: The flatflex is apparently meant to be soldered onto PCB. No need for obscure connector.

Comment: @Chupacabras good point, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find a datasheet for your specific display module. These 128x32 modules come in different variants with pinouts capable of SPI, IIC and other communication protocols. The datasheet for those usually contains a reference breakout to each available mode with capacitor values and recommendations.

In my project I’ve used one 128x64 module with 30 pin flex cable. And breakout was rather complex. I would not recommend using dayasheet of any other modules even if they look similar as recommended breakout schematics and component values can be quite different.